# Split number interval into X smaller intervals

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, numbers, intervals

I'm working on a client-server application that calculates prime numbers in a given interval. Client is finished but i am stuck with server. I'm looking for algorithm that splits given interval into X (number of clients connected) smaller ones. (for example 2 - 50 with 5 clients would split into 2-10 11-20 21-30 31-40 41-50)
Can someone help me to find useable algorithm? Thanks.

Found this code, but doesn't work for large numbers

```
    private static string[] divide(ulong min, ulong max, ulong parts)
    {
        if (min > max) return null;
        List<string> list = new List<string>(); 
        ulong chunksize = max / parts;
        ulong chunkstart = min;
        ulong chunkend = chunkstart + chunksize - 1;
        while(chunkstart < max)
        {
            if(chunkend > max)
            {
                list.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", chunkstart, max));
                break;
            }
            list.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1}", chunkstart, chunkend));
            chunkstart += chunksize;
            chunkend += chunksize;
        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code which you started to write. Also, some arrangement (data) will be helpful.

Comment: Edited main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot. Check that the value of argument "parts" is used to divide the length of the interval and NOT the max value as you did. And this code also accounts for the remainder and distributes it 1-by-1 to the intervals at the beginning. That's why for your input (min:2, max:50, parts:5), it gives the output

2:12
12:22
22:32
32:41
41:50

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var x = Divide(2, 50, 5);
        foreach(var y in x) Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", y.Item1, y.Item2);
    }
    private static List<Tuple<ulong, ulong>> Divide(ulong min, ulong max, ulong parts) 
    {
        ulong stepSize = (max - min) / parts;
        if (stepSize <= 0) return null;

        ulong mod = (max - min) % parts;
        var result = new List<Tuple<ulong, ulong>>();
        ulong begin = min;
        ulong end;
        for (ulong i = 0; i < parts; i++) 
        {
            end = begin + stepSize;
            if (mod > 0)
            {
                mod--;
                end += 1;
            }
            var t = new Tuple<ulong, ulong>(begin, end);
            result.Add(t);
            begin = end;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```